# Creating Get Rest Request with S3 path for transactions

Tags: java, spring, rest, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a rest api that takes as a variable path a path from s3 (aws) and I have some problems.

1. `GetMapping(value="files/{filePath}", produces="application/json")`
   If I give for example the path: `myFiles/uni/mymarks.txt`, it does not treat it as a variable but as a full path so it cannot map it. Any recommendations of how i can give it as a variable? (slashes create this issue).
2. If I have in the filePath variable something like `name.txt` it keeps only the name and removes the `.txt` so the name is not correct when I want to use it later on the code. Any adjustments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about?

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/files/**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> s3ProxyGet(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String path = new UrlPathHelper().getPathWithinApplication(request);
    ...
```

Then:

`curl http://localhost:8080/files/uni/mymarks.txt`

will map to this controller method and `path` will contain `/files/uni/mymarks.txt`.  You can then trim `/files` from the front and perform the fetch from s3.

`UrlPathHelper` is from the `spring-web` library.

HTH

Comment: Great.  Glad I could help.  In return if the solution works then can you accept it as the answer or up-vote please?